# unresolved reference NotificationCompat even after adding support library

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to use notification for sdk above 4.4.

I've add support library to my code and this is my build.gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.51'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation project(':Library:rangeseekbar')
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.12.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.github.hamsaadev:Persian-Date-Picker-Dialog:V1.2'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.firdausmaulan:GlideSlider:1.3.1'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
```

but when i try to add **NotificationCompat** into KT class inside project it gives unresolved reference error.

[image]

and the code :

```
import android.app.Notification
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log;
import okhttp3.*
import io.socket.client.IO
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter
import io.socket.client.Socket
import org.jetbrains.anko.AnkoAsyncContext
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.os.Build
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.graphics.Color
import com.khcai.mifrooshe.R
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

    class SocketListener : WebSocketListener() {
        private var mSocket: Socket? = null
        private var SOCKET_SERVER_URL  = "http://10.0.2.2:6001/"
        private var outsideContext : Context? = null
        fun start(context : Context?) {

            outsideContext = context
            mSocket = IO.socket(SOCKET_SERVER_URL);

            mSocket!!.on("App\\Events\\NotificationEvent", NotificationEvent)

            attemptLogin()
        }

        private fun attemptLogin() {

            val `object` = JSONObject()
            try {
                `object`.put("channel", "everyone")
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                return
            }
            mSocket!!.connect()
            mSocket!!.emit("subscribe", `object`)
        }


        private val NotificationEvent = Emitter.Listener { args ->

                try {
                    val data = args[1] as JSONObject

                    val msg = data.getString("msg")
                  //  Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show();
                    var builder = Notification.Builder(outsideContext)
                            .setContentTitle("New Message")
                            .setContentText(msg)
                            .build();
                    Log.e("server msg: ", msg)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("TAG error : ", e.message)

                }


        }
        private val c = AtomicInteger(0)
        var Notification_ID = c.incrementAndGet()
        fun showNotification(from: String, notification: String, intent: Intent) {
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    outsideContext,
                    Notification_ID,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
            val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01"
            val notificationManager = outsideContext?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
                    as NotificationManager

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                        "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

                // Configure the notification channel.
                notificationChannel.description = "Channel description"
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
                notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
                notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 1000, 500, 1000)
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            }
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(outsideContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            val mNotification = builder
                    .setContentTitle(from)
                    .setContentText(notification)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(outsideContext?.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .build()

            notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/Notification_ID, mNotification)

        }


    }
```

im using notification inside websocket service to notify user from server respond. 
ive even invalidate the cache reclean gradle build. but still no hope.

Comment: You need to share your code as text not as image

Comment: have u try to import `import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`?

Comment: @NileshRathod yes, its gives error on "app" part of it.

Comment: @AhadPorkar Did you get this to work? if yes, can you please post your answer!

Comment: @stack_ved after adding "import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat" and resync the gradle the problem solved